# Resizing problems

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I'm trying to put this illustration onto the whiteboard (left) But when I try to shrink it, it gets all messed up. I tried doing path-outline stroke. It worked but I losst all the color that had already been filled.

[image]

Comment: can you attach the file

Answer (score 1):

Since this is more complex graphic, use **Object > Expand...** rather than  'Outline Stroke.' While these are pretty similar commands, the expand option is a bit more in depth, handling strokes, fills, gradients (if applicable) and will maintain the proportions of your original artwork while resizing:

[image]
*^ Expand Options Menu*

For a nice summary on 'Outline Stroke' vs. 'Expand' (and when to use each), 
check out [Cai's answer on this question.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/77261/difference-between-expand-and-outline-stroke-in-adobe-illustrator)